# Infinite root systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, infinitary-combinatorics

The definition of [root system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system) on Wikipedia specifies that a root system must be a finite set of vectors. If we relax this restriction (while still in finite dimensions, i.e. $\Bbb R^n$), do we get any new root systems? Or to rephrase without referencing the definition of "root system":

> Does there exist a set $\Phi\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ such that:
>
> 1. $\Phi$ is a spanning set
> 2. If $x\in\Phi$ then $ax\in\Phi\to a=\pm1$
> 3. If $x,y\in\Phi$ then $\langle y,x\rangle :=2\dfrac{(x,y)}{(x,x)}$ is an integer, and $y-\langle y,x\rangle x\in\Phi$
> 4. $\Phi$ is infinite?

Obviously the answer is no in dimensions $0,1$, but even in dimension $2$ I'm not seeing any clear argument for or against. The strict constraints on possible finite solutions suggests to me that no infinite solutions exist, but I'm not clear on the usual argumentation here and I can't see any nontrivial reductions of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's still true that there are only a finite set of possible angles between two roots in a root system. Given infinitely many vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which aren't scalar multiples of each other), the angles between them must get arbitrarily small (basically because the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ is compact).

Comment: Do you know an effective bound on the number of vectors possible given the dimension $n$? It seems like you could get a ballpark figure with the surface area of $S^{n-1}$ divided by the solid angle of a circle of radius $15^{\circ}$, but then there is also the sphere packing density to account for.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro For large enough $n$ the number of vectors is equal to $n(n+1)$, $2n^2$, or $2n(n-1)$, assuming we're still talking about root systems.

Comment: @MattSamuel I suppose that's true - I guess I was trying to avoid directly applying the classification theorem. (Edit: actually, doesn't that assume you are talking about *irreducible* root systems?)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I edited my comment too, and you're right about your edit. Allowing reducible root systems does make counting the number of vectors more interesting.

Comment: @MattSamuel At least from an order-of-magnitude estimate, though, $2n^2$ should still be an upper bound, since the root system join operation has $|\Phi\sqcup\Psi|=|\Phi|+|\Psi|$ in dimension $d(\Phi)+d(\Psi)$, so it should contibute only an $O(n)$ increase as a function of dimension (and you can easily verify $2n^2$ as an upper bound since $2m^2+2n^2\le2(m+n)^2$).

Answer (score 4):

For a positive definite bilinear form, the classified finite root systems are the only ones that can exist (up to isomorphism). If we allow arbitrary, possibly degenerate, bilinear forms we can get infinite root systems that satisfy these axioms. These correspond to the root systems of infinite dimensional Kac-Moody Lie algebras. If we then drop the condition that $\langle x,y\rangle$ be an integer, we essentially obtain the concept of the root system of an arbitrary finitely generated Coxeter group, which is usually infinite.